# Is my understanding of conjugate acid-base pairs correct?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

$$\ce{HCl_{(aq)} + H_2O_{(l)}<=>H_3O^{+}_{(aq)} +Cl^{-}_{(aq)}}$$

Cl- is the conjugate base of HCl. Now, can I say that HCl is the conjugate acid of Cl-?

Comment: If you have performed a simple search, the [Wikipedia page Conjugate acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_acid) would tell you you can.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the Arrhenius sense, exactly yes.

Replace Cl- with some arbitrary species A-, and HCl with HA, and you get the exact Arrheniusian definition.

Comment: Rather by the Broensted-Lawry model. By the Arrhenius model, Cl- nor NH3 are not bases, only fictitious NH4OH is.